# lucene indexSearch.search performance

Tags: java, performance, search, lucene, out-of-memory

I'm using lucene4.2 and have an index whose documents have more than 50 fields.
The index contains about 80 mio. documents and is 11.5 GB in size.
Every query more than 20 seconds.
something like this:

```
//Query: +(id:[3000000000000000000 TO 9000000000000000000]) +(devId:2 devId:3)
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
TopDocs topDocs = indexSearch.search(query,1000);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
logger.info(end - start);
```

It caused an OutOfMemoryError When the JVM heap size less than 1024M.
I'm really confused as to why it takes so much memory and time.
How can I do to make searches in 1 second?

Comment: How did you create the index? 80 mio. documents is 80, 000, 000 documents? If so, 1G memory may not be enough.

Comment: 3 quintillion to 9 quintillion is quite a large range, and I assume finds an awful lot of hits.  If you narrow that range, do you see the same problem.

Comment: Here is my parameter.mergeFactor 100  useCompoundFile false OPenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND.You mean it will be faster split into multiple indexes?  The id is not auto increment and it calculated through the current time.

Comment: Yes, I narrow the range,but did not reduce the search time.

Answer (score 0):

how did you create document field?  did you store all fields?

it could be the field you stored is large